# How to get Italian High School transcript for UK University admission

Tags: university, united-kingdom, transcript-of-records, italy

**UPDATE:**
If no transcript is available it seems that the 4 pages paper certificate given with the diploma, where are stated the number of hours for each topic and for each year, comprehensive of the vote for each section of the final exam, is enough. I'm waiting for their confirmation for the final update.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**
I'm trying to enroll in a UK university (University of London) and they are asking me for an official transcript of my studies in Italy.
I graduated from High School back in 2007/2008 and my former school has no idea what a transcript is or how to do it as it's something that does not exists in Italy. The diploma has legal value so there's no need to prove your grades, they have no idea even about how to give me the study plan transcription of the subject I studied as it's all non-digitalized and

> "it will take months to copy that from the archive"

(yes they said months).

Did anyone ever experience something like this? As it seems that the transcript is essential for the enrolment process, how can you solved it?

Comment: Have you contacted the admissions team at the U of L and explained this, and asked them to advise? I would expect them to be helpful.

Comment: I'm trying to enrol in an 100% online BSc that is based on Coursera. I've tried to ask their counselors but they've only been able to tell me to send everything I have and then see what happens next. I would like to have the documentation as complete as possible to avoid problems.

Comment: I think all you can do is follow their advice. Perhaps the diploma itself is enough (I think it is for many courses at my university, but for some courses it needs evidence of specific courses taken).

Comment: "I'm trying to enrol in an 100% online BSc that is based on Coursera." Undergraduate admission is off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appear to be a combination of terminology and mechanisation. When applying and registering for things online the replies you get will be automated containing fixed stock phrases that suit most circumstances. You are dealing with a database engine not a human.

How do I know? Because someone like me is on the other side of the database engine. We can only click buttons to send certain phrases in stock replies when processing student admissions.

What you have described is what they expect for a transcript. A set of results in detail. What you have imagined is something different, perhaps due to miss-translation and different uses of the terminology. Just submit the four pages of details saying "here is my Italian transcript". They may need a certified translation from Italian, but that is all.

Admission staff deal with admissions documents in all formats from all countries on the globe. They just need proof you completed high school and the grades. They need to know a little more detail than "I passed" because they usually need to check that you completed things like Mathematics (and are numerate), that you are literate, how much STEM subjects you completed and so on.